# OpenLayers 3 MapQuest Tiles

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3, mapquest

As of today, July 11th 2016 MapQuest has blocked direct access to there tiles.

Is there a good alternative for projection EPSG:4326?

Comment: you can use any tile service and reproject the tiles to `4326`